# Is there an uninstaller or similar program for Windows that generates a log file?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I am not so concerned with uninstalling but rather seeing what has been installed.

Some uninstaller programs make a snapshot of the Windows system before and after a setup.exe file has run but do any produce a log file?

Ideally the log file would list all of the following:

-files added to Program Files;

-shortcuts added to the Start Menu and desktop;

-dlls and other files added to the Windows folder; and

-new registry entries.

Windows XP compatibility is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

#### Snapshot comparison

- Registry only (free): [Nirsoft RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html)
- registry only (Open Source): [RegShot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/)
- File and Registry (commercial): [SysTracer](https://www.blueproject.ro/systracer)

Additionally some similar, older can be found on the Internet that are discontinued and no longer available on their developers web sites like [WhatChanged](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/whatchanged-portable).

#### Generate the log in real-time

Using [Microsoft Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) you can generate an complete access log what have been changed at real-time.

The tool also supports file and registry (as well as network and processes). As is also shows not only changes to file-system and registry you need to configure it first (e.g. ignore access by standard Windows processes and disable read access) which can take some time as the incoming events rate is high.